# Adding id to pages in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-pageshow

For internal linking in jquery mobile, I seem to need adding unique id to each page div so that I can handle each page separately. Since the page div itself is being generated by jquery mobile dynamically, what is the best practice to add dynamic id to those divs?

Edit:
Currently I am requesting new page as follows:

```
$(document).on("swipeleft", function () {
    nextpage = GetNextPage();
    $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", nextpage, { changeHash: true });
});
```

where nextpage is a dynamic url. I use this approach to allow paging.

Comment: Actually you have to provide the page divs and mark them as data-role="page". Then jQM will enhance the divs as pages.  When you provide the divs to jQM just give them unique ids that make sense within your app.

Comment: Well the divs are dynamic and I can't define all divs that I might need. Currently by default jqm creates those divs for me.

Comment: How do you dynamically create the pages?

Comment: This code is to navigate to a page, how do you inject the page dynamically into DOM? Is the page an external file.html?

Comment: Actually I invoke it by swiping, sorry for not adding the whole function please check it now.

Comment: That code itself navigate and injects the new page in DOM.

Comment: ok, what does `GetNextPage()` do exactly? Does it create a page dynamically and _append_ into DOM? Can show us that fucntion?

Comment: GetNextPage returns a url only. Please check the method here: http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64895/discussion-between-omar-and-abu-lamar).